# Send only changed form fields from dynamic form on save in smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt

How can I send only changed/edited form fields from dynamic form in smartgwt. 
For eg; Say dynamic form has got 10 fields, I edit only 2 fields. Then only 2 edited/changed fields should go in the request for saving the form.

Any ideas how to send only changed/edited form fields in the request.
Please share ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Form's current values are accessible as [DynamicForm#getValues()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html#getValues%28%29).

Look at [DynamicForm#rememberValues()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html#rememberValues%28%29), [DynamicForm#setValues()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html#setValues%28java.util.Map%29) and [DynamicForm#resetValues()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html#resetValues%28%29) also.

---

Try this sample code to get the edited values.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    VLayout vLayout = new VLayout();

    ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    comboBoxItem.setShowTitle(false);
    comboBoxItem.setValueMap("mouse", "cat", "cow", "dog");

    TextItem textItem = new TextItem();
    textItem.setShowTitle(false);

    CheckboxItem checkboxItem = new CheckboxItem();
    checkboxItem.setShowTitle(false);
    checkboxItem.setTitle("");

    final DynamicForm dynamicForm = new DynamicForm();
    dynamicForm.setItems(comboBoxItem, checkboxItem, textItem);

    vLayout.addMember(dynamicForm);

    // default values
    textItem.setValue("abc");
    comboBoxItem.setValue("cat");
    checkboxItem.setValue(true);

    // Remember values
    dynamicForm.rememberValues();

    // store default values
    final Map<?, ?> defaultValues = dynamicForm.getValues();

    Button button = new Button("check");
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Map<?, ?> newValues = dynamicForm.getValues();

            for (Object key : defaultValues.keySet()) {
                if (!defaultValues.get(key).equals(newValues.get(key))) {
                    System.out.println(key + " - old value: " + defaultValues.get(key)
                            + " - new value: " + newValues.get(key));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    vLayout.addMember(button);

    RootPanel.get().add(vLayout);
}
```

output:

```
    isc_TextItem_0 - old value: abc - new value: xyz
    isc_ComboBoxItem_0 - old value: cat - new value: cow
    isc_CheckboxItem_0 - old value: true - new value: false
```

snapshot:

[image]

---

Try with [DSRequest#setOldValues()](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/server/javadoc/com/isomorphic/datasource/DSRequest.html#setOldValues%28java.util.Map%29).

Sample code not tested:

```
    DSRequest requestProperties=new DSRequest();
    requestProperties.setOldValues(oldValues);

    dynamicForm.saveData(new DSCallback() {

        @Override
        public void execute(DSResponse dsResponse, Object data, DSRequest dsRequest) {
           ...                
        }
    }, requestProperties);
```